# Connect to Master Database in Azure SQL DW

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

I'm Trying to Connect to Master database for my Azure SQL DW system but getting this error:

[image]

My SQL Account is part of `db_owner` group.

Do I need to configure any additional access for this SQL account?

Answer (score 2):

As a db_owner for the database, you don't necessarily have rights to the server. You will need to connect to the master database using credentials that have rights and add your login as a db_owner to master.